# Rails, Ruby, how to sort an Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

in my rails app I'm creating an array like so:

```
@messages.each do |message|

  @list << {
    :id => message.id,
    :title => message.title,
    :time_ago => message.replies.first.created_at
  }
end
```

After making this array I would like to then sort it by time_ago ASC order, is that possible?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
 @list.sort_by{|e| e[:time_ago]}
```

it defaults to ASC, however if you wanted DESC you can do:

```
 @list.sort_by{|e| -e[:time_ago]}
```

Also it seems like you are trying to build the list from `@messages`. You can simply do:

```
@list = @messages.map{|m| 
  {:id => m.id, :title => m.title, :time_ago => m.replies.first.created_at }
}
```

Comment: So I do this before I build @list ? or? I'm tried it after and it errors with: NoMethodError (undefined method `time_ago' for #<Hash:0x10e8ac1e0>):

Comment: You do this after you build `@list`. So `@messages.each do |message|

  @list << {
    :id => message.id,
    :title => message.title,
    :time_ago => message.replies.first.created_at
  }
end`

`@list.sort_by...`

Comment: For DESC, tried that got, undefined method `-@' for Wed Apr 20 20:40:35 UTC 2011:Time

Comment: @list = @list.sort_by { |e| -e[:time_ago] }

Comment: hmm, weird that works fine for me. What Ruby version are you running? Also look at my updated answer to help condense your code.

Comment: In the absolute worst case that you still wanted to do this programmatically (as in not via SQL), you can do `@list.sort_by{|e| e[:time_ago]}.reverse` but that really weird that it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Mike that did the trick. thanks! It is weird, I like your idea about condensing the code, but the hash I'm creating has about 10 values, I just cut it down to keep the question clean and simple. If I did the one line approach I worry that would kill readability

Comment: or you can do `@list.sort { |a, b| b[:time_ago] <=> a[:time_ago] }` though it is not as readable.

Comment: @ColdTree The reason you got 'undefined method' was because you were attempting to negate a time value, like -Wednesday, which doesn't make sense. Mike Lewis assumed that :time_ago was a numeric value. You have to subtract `Time.now - message.replies.first.created_at` to get a numeric `:time_ago` and then the reverse sort will work.

Comment: I am facing issues while using sort or sort_by in my presenter and controller. It says undefined method 'sort_by' . Can any one shed light on this?

Answer (score 15):

In rails 4+

```
@list.sort_by(&:time_ago)
```

Answer (score 12):

You could do:

```
@list.sort {|a, b| a[:time_ago] <=> b[:time_ago]}
```

Comment: Better yet, `@list.sort_by { |m| m[:time_ago] }`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do `@list.sort_by { |message| message.time_ago }`

Comment: Thanks but how do you define the sorting order?

Comment: You define the sorting order with the `{ |message| message.time_ago }` part. It's called `sort_by` because it sorts by the criteria in the block. Here, we're saying to sort by the `.time_ago` member of the elements. It always sorts ascending. To sort descending, we can sort ascending by the negative of that value, as described in Mike Lewis' answer. :) If it doesn't work, it's because whatever type `time_ago` has doesn't define negation. :/

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI, I don't see the point in moving the messages into a new list and then sorting them. As long as it is ActiveRecord it should be done directly when querying the database in my opinion.

It looks like you should be able to do it like this:

```
@messages = Message.includes(:replies).order("replies.created_at ASC")
```

That should be enough unless I have misunderstood the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use group_by :

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Comment: Rails 4 breaks this link. The old documentation can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Comment: it's about sorting not grouping