# rails - mysql joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am trying to do a basic report here

- Show a list of users with details like names, age etc.
- Also show other details like number of posts, last activity time etc.
- All these other details are in a has_many relation from users

This is what I am doing right now:

```
User.find(
          :all, 
          :select => "users.id, users.name, count(distinct(posts.id)) as posts_count",
          :joins => "left outer join posts on posts.user_id = users.id",
          :group => "users.id",
          :limit => "100"
)
```

Have indexed the **user_id** column in posts table

My problem is it is taking a very long time to do this and sometimes hangs when I try to do more tables along with posts like activities, comments etc.

Is there a way join the count alone or some other way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think one of these might work, but as always when doing an outer join, the query will be slower.

```
User.count(:include=>[:posts])

User.count(:select => "users.id, users.name, count(distinct(posts.id)) as posts_count",
          :joins => "left outer join posts on posts.user_id = users.id",
          :group => "users.id")

User.find(:all, :include => [:posts])
```

Also you can put in an initializer file or irbrc file this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
```

And check the queries as you type them in console.

For post count

```
User.all.posts.size
```

As far as reporting each post count later you can do that with the User record you have already.

```
@users = User.find(:all, :include=> [:posts])
```

Later ...

```
<% @users.each do |user|
  Posts: <%= user.posts.size %>
<% end %>
```

Users sorted by post

```
@sorted_users = @users.sort_by{|user| user.posts.size }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5739222/1354978

Comment: How do you suppose I should include the count of posts? Sorry if what I am asking is very basic

Comment: there is one problem with this approach.. how do you sort the users based on the number of posts?

Comment: I would rather not sort the users in ruby but offload it to the database